# Android: Custom border for FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am trying to add a custom border to a `framelayout`. The `framelayout` is used as container for the fragment. Thus I want to display fragment with a border. The border should be external to framelayout and should not consume the space inside of framelayout. And it should adjust with change in screen size.

[image]

What i can think right now is some sort of custom ViewGroup, add ImageView for border. Use image processing to get the inside area of imageview and in that area inflate a frame layout.

I am looking for some easy way out.

Comment: One solution would be breaking that image in 3 parts(2 left and right strips and another image with the center content) and calculating the strips width. You would used that calculated value to set left and right padding on the ViewGroup where the image will be used as background.Those 3 images could be then composed in a custom drawable to obtain the full image

Answer (score 5):

The easiest solution for this would be to create a 9-patch drawable and set it as the background for your FrameLayout. I have created the below 9-patch drawable that you can use. Hope this suffice your requirement.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain the effect via layout XML using for example `LinearLayout`s with proper layout_weight, so your centre-most FrameLayout will expand to take up available space.

There are 4 drawables used: for top, bottom, left and right part of frame.

Check out this code:

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/border_left" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/border_top" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <!-- FrameLayout content goes here -->

            </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/border_top" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_conttXY"
        android:layout_height="match_parght"
        android:scaleType="fient"
        android:src="@drwable/border_right" />

</LinearLayout>
```